# Disable directory listing with a custom message using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to disable a directory listing using .htaccess.

I don't want to show any `404 not found` or `403 forbidden` error messages.

Suppose when a user will try to access the directory `www.mydomain.com/data/uploads`, then only a custom message will show like `Hi, this is not a page you are looking for`.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your .htaccess:

```
# disable directory listing
Options -Indexes

# show a custom message
ErrorDocument 403 "Hi, this is not a page you are looking for"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option, which would send a 200 response and not use a custom errordoc for any other 403 in the same context, would be to set a low priority DirectoryIndex with your custom error message.

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html lastchance.html
```